# Cassandra: clear HDD space AFTER columnfamily was dropped

Tags: cassandra

This is how it is - I dropped the whole keyspace but the space was not restored due to *gc_grace_seconds* thing which is standard - 10 days. How to **clear the space** *immediately*? Tried nodetool flush, compact, restarting the node - didn't help. It's a single-node cluster, no worries about synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guy from the cassandra IRC helped me - I just need to remove all the old snapshots, like that:

nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot